# Image on image after selecting option

Tags: html, css

I am looking to achieve a similar effect as [here:](http://www.easternairways.fr/map)

I have an image in a `route-map` element, serving as a background. Upon selecting an option in a form, I would like for the upper layer on the background to change. If I choose for example Option 1, the picture on top of the map would change. And same for other options.

How can I achieve this? I'm completely clueless on how to change an image based upon option selected in a form.

Comment: You can try with `javascript`, it should get the job done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make "upper layer" as an image with transparent background. Image is absolutely positioned and initially invisible. Upon selection a JS function is called to make it visible. Something like:

**HTML:**

```
<img src="map.gif"/>
<img id="line" src="line.png" />
<hr/>

<select onchange="displayLine()">
    <option></option>
    <option>Connect</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
#line {
   position: absolute;
   top:170px;
   left:140px;

   height:100px;
   width:150px;    

   display:none;

}
```

**JS**

```
function displayLine() {
    document.getElementById("line").style.display="block";
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/U82LA/1/